# Tuple values not being accurately compared in game logic

Tags: python, boolean, tuples

I am refactoring code for a Tic-Tac-Toe application in Python however i am running into trouble when rewriting the function that checks for a winning condition.

This is what i have right now

```
x = ('X', 'X', 'X')
o = ('O', 'O', 'O')

if ('X', '-', '-') == o or x:
    print(True)
```

This returns True even though the string shown is clearly not either one of the ones it's been compared to. However what is even weirder is that when I compare it to just one tuple

```
if ('X', '-', '-') == o:
    print(True)
```

True doesn't get returned. Can someone please explain why this happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay let's break this down. The way you have your code written, you have **two** things you're comparing to see if they're "truthy":

- `('X', '-', '-') == o`
- `x`

The half of your `or` conditional is `x` itself. Since a tuple with values is considered truthy, your condition (everything after `if`) will *always* evaluate to true! If you're trying to compare `('X', '-', '-')` to `o` and to `x`, you'll need to do this:

`if ('X', '-', '-') == o or ('X', '-', '-') == x`